# Android - GsmCellLocation and getCid() error

Tags: android, cell

i am trying to obtain cellId and Lac value, but i still get "stopped unexpectedly" error.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    GsmCellLocation loc = (GsmCellLocation) tm.getCellLocation();

    TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);

    text.setText(loc.getCid());
}
```

It is very simple program and i found it many times in this form, but it does work neither in emulator (in emulators i have 2.3.3 and 3.0), nor in telephone (tablet 3.0)

Permissions i have try in manifest:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"></uses-permission>
```

Thanks for reply, Jirka

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled the use of wireless networks for localization in the settings? On android 2.3.4 you can do it settings->location->Use Wireless Network. Enable it. Now your code should run !

Answer (score 0):

In case you are still looking for an answer to this question, the problem is that loc.getCid() returns an integer whereas text.setText requires a String. Just change the last line to:

```
text.setText(Integer.toString(loc.getCid()));
```

I just tried this and it works fine.

One other point, although I'm not sure about this (and I would be curious to hear others' experiences): You seem to be assuming that you are running this on a GSM phone. What if `tm.getCellLocation()` returns a `CdmaCellLocation` instead? Since there is no `get.Cid()` method for the `CdmaCellLocation` class, I would think that it is safer to enclose your code in an `if` statement like: `if(tm.getPhoneType() == TelephonyManager.PHONE_TYPE_GSM)`. You could also then have a separate outcome for `if(tm.getPhoneType() == TelephonyManager.PHONE_TYPE_CDMA)`using one of the available [methods](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/cdma/CdmaCellLocation.html).